# Create OBD2 MUT scanner by using Java FTDI lib - jd2xx - openport1.3 usb cable

Tags: java, ftdi, obd-ii

I am trying to create a Java obd2 scanner app for my mitsubishi lancer mx 1997 which use MUTII protocol over OBD2. Can anybody help me to read [MUT request codes](http://evoecu.logic.net/wiki/MUT_Requests) using [jd2xx](http://bleyer.org/jd2xx/) library.
I have tried the below program, but it didn read engine RPM.

```
package lancerscan;

import jd2xx.JD2XX;

public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    JD2XX jd = new JD2XX();
    jd.open(0);
    jd.setBaudRate(38400);
    jd.setDataCharacteristics(
            8, JD2XX.STOP_BITS_1, JD2XX.PARITY_NONE);
    jd.setFlowControl(
            JD2XX.FLOW_NONE, 0, 0);
    jd.setTimeouts(1000, 1000);

    String msg = "21";
    int ret = jd.write(msg.getBytes());
    System.out.println(ret + " bytes sent.");

    int rd = jd.read();
    System.out.println(">>>" + rd);

    int status = jd.getQueueStatus();
    byte[] data = new byte[(int) status];
    long lngBytesReturned = jd.read(data, 0, data.length);

    System.out.println("======= " + lngBytesReturned);
    }
}
```

MUT request code for Engine RPM is 0x21
more MUT request codes can be found [here](http://evoecu.logic.net/wiki/MUT_Requests)

similar C programs which works fine is [here](https://github.com/harshadura/Lancer-Scan/blob/master/test.c); main prjct files are [here](https://github.com/harshadura/Lancer-Scan)

Thanks,
harsha

Answer (score 2):

First your using a different baud rate to that in the example. The example uses `15625 baud` but you are using `38400 baud`.

Secondly you are missing some of the setup commands. I am not sure if this will make a difference but its something that is different between your code and the example.

Mitsubishi require you to set the car ECU into diagnostic mode by sending `0x00` at a rate of `5 baud` on one of the pins. On the OpenPort 1.3D cable this translates to setting the break to on for `1800 ms` and then turning it off. You can see this is done with the `ftdimut_init()` command from the [libftdimut.c](https://github.com/harshadura/Lancer-Scan/blob/32e7f14797f666b1f9edabaceb0d9ae190435f52/libftdimut.c) file.

```
      printf("Sending 0x00 at 5 baud\n");

      printf("Break on......\n");
      ftStatus = FT_SetBreakOn(ftdimut_ftHandle);
      if(ftStatus != FT_OK) return ftStatus;
      ftdimut_msleep(1800);
      printf("Break off......\n");
      ftStatus = FT_SetBreakOff(ftdimut_ftHandle);
      if(ftStatus != FT_OK) return ftStatus;
```

The car ECU will then send you 4 bytes containing the ECU ID. This can then be used to check the ECU correctly entered diagnostic mode. You can see this in [libftdimut.c](https://github.com/harshadura/Lancer-Scan/blob/32e7f14797f666b1f9edabaceb0d9ae190435f52/libftdimut.c).

```
      ftStatus = FT_Read(ftdimut_ftHandle, buf, 4, &bytesRead);
      if(ftStatus != FT_OK) return ftStatus;

      if(bytesRead == 4) {
        return FT_OK;
      }
```

Now assuming that you got the 4 bytes back you can start to send the diagnostic codes such as `0x17` or `0x21`.

Answer (score 1):

I just saw your post on my blog, niallm answer is correct, you need to do a 5 baud init first which involves driving the KLine, you can use something like the 5 baud init posted in that answer, more info about the protocol:

http://evoecu.logic.net/wiki/MUT_Protocol

After getting a 4 byte response you can start sending requests at 15625 baud (I'm communicating with a 94 3000GT so the CEL light stops blinking), also in my case I send the converted values (0x21 = 33 decimal) as a byte array.

Comment: seems like setting baud to 5 isnt possible with jd2xx, it gives me a IOexpection saying. 
`Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: other error (-1)
        at jd2xx.JD2XX.setBaudRate(Native Method)
        at lancerscan.Test.main(Test.java:11)
Java Result: ` 
Javadoc: http://home.arcor.de/mbussi/Sim-Doc/jd2xx/JD2XX.html#setBaudRate%28int%29 could you please provide me a working example of this kind of program? thank you.

Comment: Sure, drive the K-line with breaks:
    jd.setBreakOn(); 
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1800);
    } 
    catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    jd.setBreakOff(); 
    int bytesAvailable = jd.getQueueStatus();
    if(bytesAvailable == 4){
        System.out.println("INIT complete");
    }

Comment: Thanks, But how can i use baud 5 with this code to init. using baud 5 for is not possible with jd2xx ? can u suggest an equivalent baud to use.

Comment: You can't set that baud rate, that's why you use the above code, to drive the K line as the MUT protocol init requires, sending 0x00 at 5 baud (200ms interval), 0000 0000 1 <-- stop bit, the first 8 bits are the 0x00, sent at 200ms intervals (1800ms with the k-line low),  after the 1800ms break the last bit is the stop bit.

Comment: Hi Reses, Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong here. I have written this program now: https://gist.github.com/harshadura/0ec66ff67064d653060b i get a reply saying: `1
2
3
4
INIT complete
2 bytes sent.
Engine RPM : >>> 6`

Comment: I think that you should read the queue before sending another INIT:

byte[] rd = jd.read(bytesAvailable);

If it was a 4 byte read, switch to 15625 and start sending requests:

    int available= jd.getQueueStatus();
    if(available==2){
        byte[] response = jd.read(available);
        System.out.println("Engine RPM : >>> " + response[1]);
    }

Comment: hi Reses, it doesn't work. Could you please provide me a working code sample, thanks lot.